# After setstate table 1st row overlaps header row

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, setstate

Once setstate done, table reloads fresh data but table top row going inside header row. I found dynamically adding `tranform:translate(0px,-16px)`. I tried to change CSS but after that scroll not working. Plz see the screenshot once.

[image: setstateTableIssueImage]

```
<Table keygen="peer" fixed="both" style={{ maxHeight: 600 }} columns={columns} data={dataResponse} format="id" width={width} />
```

after executing of below setstate above issue getting, this setstate is not related to table

```
 this.setState({ isTableEmptyFlag:false,templates: templatesList,  })
```

Comment: going to need some more info here.  is this table from a package? can you show the relevant code that renders and sets state?

Comment: @DMcCallum83 added sample code, plz check